# Get C:\Users Programmatically

Tags: c#, .net-3.5

As far as I know de standard folder for Users (usually C:\Users) can be changed (e.g. C:\xzy\Users).

Is it possible to get the Users directory?

Or is there a method to get the path to the DefaultUser Directory?

I have to handle this in .NET Framework 3.5

EDIT: The other Problem is, when the application is running as a service user (e.g. System) the %userprofile% will be located somewhere in C:\Windows

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was doing something else when I saw something that reminded me of this question.

The data you're looking for lives in the registry.

Read it like this:

```
(string)Registry.GetValue(
  @"HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList",
  "ProfilesDirectory","")
```

Your app will need sufficient privileges to read the registry.

Answer (score 3):

```
string userFolderpath = System.IO.Directory.GetParent
(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData)).FullName;

string userFolderParentPath = System.IO.Directory.GetParent(path).FullName ;
```

Comment: Hmm.... this would give me %userprofile%\appdata because Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData resolves to %userprofile%\appdata\roaming . Why not use the parent of the %userprofile% special folder?

Comment: UserProfile is not availabe in 3.5...
The other Problem is, when the application is running as a service user (e.g. System) the %userprofile% will be located somewhere in C:\Windows

Answer (score 2):

you can see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.specialfolder.aspx